# How to convert number to dollar format

Tags: sql, db2

I wrote sql to convert number to dollar format by referring other stackoverflow questions.

```
select decimal(sum_price, 9, 2) from order_tbl
```

The data type of column `sum_price` is `Decimal(10,0)`.

if number in column is `7050`, this SQL return `7084.00`, but what I want is 
`70.84`.

what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't convert in implicit way this.

If you have stored your field in `decimal(10,0)` you tell you have only int part stored, so you must apply a math conversion as follow:

```
SELECT sum_price * 0,01 from order_tbl
```

But... If you have stored a number as follow: 7050 where you indicate 7,050 (US separator for thousand), how query understand this situation?

I **strongly** advice to change **your field definition**

Comment: It works. Thank you!
Anyway, actual column name is sum_price, not sum. I just simplified SQL. Thank you for advice!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Select Str(float_field, 25, 5)
```

This is the link for your refrence.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx

Comment: Tag is DB2 so IBM DBMS not Microsoft